# HTML/ CSS image size

Tags: html, css, image

UPDATE* I have a problem on how my images are being resized. this is my music tab and on my css img is for another picture on the homepage tab top right. I am not sure why the picture in music tab is not fitting with the div size.. any ideas? I provided a screenshot link of [image: how my webpage looks]

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

audio {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.slider {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 50%;
}

.img-box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: "gray";
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: "white";
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="img-box">
    <img src='fl.png' class="slider-img" alt="" />
  </div>
  <!-- buttons --->
  <button class="btn" onclick="prev()"> Prev </button>
  <button class="btn" onclick="next()"> Next </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` is not `width`.

If a photo is 1200px wide, and you set `max-width` to 1920px, it will still be 1200px wide, since 1200 is smaller than 1920.

If you set `max-width` to 800px however, it will be reduced in size so it does not exceed the `max-width` property, and it will be 800px wide.

If you want to set a fixed `width` for your image, just use `width`.

Comment: I updated the code and it still persist :(

Answer (score 0):

On Your img or slider-img class you can add

```
object-fit: cover;
```

width 100% is only make your image fit to their max width, not the parent width

this will make your image fit on its parent,
you can find more details here
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp